# URL amigável com nome e id do produto dinâmicos

Tags: php, htaccess, url, url-amigável

Estou trabalhando com URLs amigáveis em site desenvolvido em PHP. Criei o arquivo .htaccess e fiz os devidos redirecionamentos de acordo com minhas necessidades. Por exemplo, a página nomedosite.com/contato.php agora está como nomedosite.com/contato . Até aí tudo bem. Agora tenho uma página chamada noticias.php que traz várias notícias para o usuário. Ao clicar em determinada notícia, é chamado o arquivo mostranoticia.php?id=2 (por exemplo id da noticia 2) e a noticia é exibida. Quero fazer com que ao clicar na noticia, a url dela seja nomedosite.com/mostranoticia/nome-da-noticia-selecionada/4. Como posso criar uma regra para isso e como fica o link no href="" do meu código?

Minha dúvida é a sintaxe da expressão regular e como fazer o nome ficar na url, já que tenho o nome salvo no banco de dados e o nome da notícia possui espaços entre as palavras e na url não posso ter esses espaços.

Comment: Poste  um exemplo do que você já fez para melhorar a compreensão.

Answer (score 0):

Já que o site ainda está em desenvolvimento, você pode apenas criar uma coluna no banco de dados com o valor da URL já convertida. Tendo apenas a necessidade de utilizar o codigo abaixo apenas na hora da publicação da noticia.

```
preg_replace('<\W+>', "-", $Url)
```

O codigo acima faz com que tudo que não seja letra ou numero seja substituido por um traço.

Recomendo deixar como função padrão do arquivo *mostrarnoticia.php* apenas identificar o *id* e caso não tenha o nome da noticia a pagina redirecionar pagina com `header(Location: http://www.exemplo.com/` para o link completo, facilitando para o visitante lembrar da noticia, ou salvar o url dela.